# jQuery - How do you say: are there any divs called x with the property display==block?

Tags: jquery

jQuery - How do you say: are there any divs called x with the property display==block?

How do you taget specific divs with specific properties in Jquery?

Thanks...

and by "called x" I mean divs with a class name of x

Comment: what do you mean by divs called x? divs with id x? divs with class x?

Comment: -1. The official jQuery documentation makes this very clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
var DivsWithDisplayBlock = $("div.x").filter(function(){
    return $(this).css("display") == "block";
});
```

This defined variable is a JQuery object, containing references to all divs with `display:block`). For instance, if you were wondering how many divs have the `display:block` property, use: `alert(DivsWithDisplayBlock.length)`.

Note: You said *`all divs called x`. I assumeed that you were talking about all DIVs with the `.x` class. Other possible ways to "call" your div:

- `#id` - ID. This should be uniquer, and occur only once. If you've defined multiple elements with ID `x`, I recommend to change `id=` to `class=`
- `[name="x"]` - Select by name.

**EDIT** (comment)
Changing attributes:

```
DivsWithDisplayBlock.css("display", "none");
```

The `.css()` method will add `display:none` to each element which is referenced by `DivsWithDisplayBlock`.

If you want to change multiple styles of the `DIV.x` elements, I recommend to use `.toggleClass("x-visible", "x-invisible")`. Define the style properties in the stylesheet (`.x-visible, .x-invisible`). When you execute the `.toggleClass(..)` method on the matched elements, the class names will swap.

Example:

```
 /* CSS*/
.x-invisible {display:none;}
.x-visible {display:block;}

/* JavaScript */
$(".x").toggleClass("x-invisible", "x-visible");
```

Comment: very nice!  and how do i now set each one to display==none?

Comment: @DJDonaL3000 See my updated answer. I have also included an alternative method to switch between `display`.

Answer (score 4):

You would target visible divs with the following selector

Id selector

```
$('#id:visible')
```

class selector

```
$('div.class:visible')
```

Comment: `display:inline-block` is also visible (not mentioning all `table-*`, etc. display values).

Answer (score 3):

```
$('div#x').filter(function() { return $(this).css('display')==='block'; }).length > 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, that depends what you mean by "x". Let's say "x" is an class, since it seems like you have multiples.

```
$('.x')       // this will select all the **elements** with a class="x"
$('div.x')    // this will select all the divs with a class="x"
```

If you want to test for certain properties, like `display:block` which is a **style**, you could do.

```
if ($('div.x').css('display') == "block") {
    // do whatever 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean you want to select all `div` elements with a certain class that have a `display` property value of `block`, you can use the [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method:

```
var divs = $(".example").filter(function() {
   return $(this).css("display") == "block"; 
});
```

You'll need to use that if you want to filter out elements with a display property of, for example, `inline-block`. If on the other hand you are just looking for visible `div` elements (i.e. not those with a `display` property value of `none`, you can use the [`visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) pseudo-selector:

```
var divs = $(".example:visible");
```